# Calculated Measure based on multiple dimensions. Ignore some dimensions

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I need to compare each item in my 5-dimensional selection 
to a cell that sits at intersection of ***just two*** dimensions

I have the following MDX:

```
WITH MEMBER [measures].[x] AS
        (
            [dim1].[dim1].[certainDim1_Member]
            ,[dim2].[dim2].[certainDim2_Member]
            ,[measures].[a]
        )
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY {[measures].[a], [measures].[x]} ON 0,
    NON EMPTY   {
                     [dim1].[dim1].children
                    *[dim2].[dim2].children
                    *[dim3].[dim3].children
                    *[dim4].[dim4].children
                    *[dim5].[dim5].children
                } ON 1
FROM [cubename]
```

The problem is the query takes into account `currentmember` of dim3, dim4, dim5.
and the result is distorted.

When I try this:

```
WITH MEMBER [measures].[x] AS
        (
             [dim1].[dim1].[certainDim1_Member]
            ,[dim2].[dim2].[certainDim2_Member]
            ,[dim3].[dim3].[all]
            ,[dim4].[dim4].[all]
            ,[dim5].[dim5].[all]
            ,[measures].[a]
        )
```

the query dies in 2+ minutes because of *memory lack*

while this

```
WITH MEMBER [measures].[x] AS
        (
             [dim1].[dim1].[certainDim1_Member]
            ,[dim2].[dim2].[certainDim2_Member]
            ,[dim3].[dim3].[all]
            ,[dim4].[dim4].[all]
            --,[dim5].[dim5].[all]
            ,[measures].[a]
        )
```

returns a result in 3 seconds.

I have to use all 5 dimensions and even more.

Comment: I would think you have some complex non-default aggregation logic for the calculation of the `All` members of dim 4 and 5 in the calculation script of your cube. This question may be very difficult to answer without knowing all the details about the calculation script, as well as the cube design (measure groups, dimensions, and their relationships). Hence I am not sure if it is well suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: following on from FrankPI MS have an active ssas forum here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/home?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to the aggregation of a set of tuples across that measure does it still function?

```
WITH MEMBER [measures].[x] AS
    Aggregate(
        {(
          [dim1].[dim1].[certainDim1_Member]
         ,[dim2].[dim2].[certainDim2_Member]
         ,[dim3].[dim3].[all]
         ,[dim4].[dim4].[all]
         ,[dim5].[dim5].[all]
         )},
        [measures].[a]
    )
```